# GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{item-path} stopped working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I am using an API call to find a file in one of our SharePoint sites, I made a flow that was running fine until Monday of this week. The API returns the "itemNotFound" error.

I have no idea what's wrong, if I call the search function the file comes back fine, but if I specify the item path then I get the error... completely at a loss what happened and how to fix it. We are using this system to create automatic files on the server so I really need to get this fixed as soon as possible.

Search API that returns 404 error:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{*site id removed for privacy*}/drive/root:/Shared%20Documents/testfile.docx`

Graph response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-09-28T16:51:18",
            "request-id": "40aeed24-7698-437e-8ce3-9a62369fbd6a",
            "client-request-id": "a9ce4951-f6af-7ee7-a8a5-a77083a88717"
        }
    }
}
```

If I try a search query that works fine and the file is found:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{*site id removed for privacy*}/drive/root/search(q='testfile.docx')`

Graph response (abreviated):

```
"createdDateTime": "2023-09-27T13:21:24Z",
        "id": "0124G6SZYNCIZEZOC6DVELGBOBQTHBRUUG",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-09-27T13:22:06Z",
        "name": "testfile.docx",
```

So I don't believe is related to Permissions missing.

The weirdest part is that it was working fine last week, and this week it simply just broke.

Comment: Works fine for me. If your `root` folder is **Shared%20Documents** then the path should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{*site id removed for privacy*}/drive/root:/testfile.docx`

Comment: Thank you user2250152, you are correct, the Shared Documents should not be part of the path, I have removed it and now works again... weird that it worked like this for months and months and just this week it stopped working. Thanks again for your reply 

Answer (score 1):

After posting the question in the Microsoft Q&A I got the followin:
/sites/{site-id}/drive is to access the default drive (document library) for the given site. We don't need to add Shared%20Documents in the path. The api is to get the items in subfolders of Shared%20Documents.

So the API GET call should look like graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{*site id removed for privacy*}/drive/root:/testfile.docx now "Shared%20Documents" should be added.

[Link to full answer on Microsoft Learn site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1377737/get-sites-((site-id))-drive-root-((item-path))-sto?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1325014#newest-answer-comment)